# Declare a property of abstract class type

Tags: c#

I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T> { ... }
```

I have some inheriting classes:

```
public Class1<T>: BaseClass<T> { ... }
public Class2<T>: BaseClass<T> { ... }
```

I would like to define a property to hold my inheriting class, how can I do that?

```
public class API{
    public BaseClass<T> MyClass { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to call it like this:

```
new API { MyClass = new Class1<MyT> };
```

Comment: And what isn't working? Besides the strange thing that the API class is missing the class keyword...

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know what `T` is for your `MyClass` property in `API`? You need either `API` to be `API<T>` or you need a non-generic base class (or interface). More context on exactly how you intent `API` to use `MyClass` would help.

Comment: Another option is to have `BaseClass<T>` derive from a non-generic class (i.e. `BaseClass`) or a non-generic interface (`IBaseClass`) and use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your method would not work because the API class does **not** have a generic type and still uses '**T**' which **has not been defined**.

You can correct your problem by using any of the following

```
public class API{
    public BaseClass<MyT> MyClass { get; set; }
}
```

**or**

```
public class API<T> {
    public BaseClass<T> MyClass { get; set; }
}

new API<MyT> { MyClass = new Class1<MyT>() };
```

In case you want to check the type **which you shouldn't need to**, you can use the **`is`** keyword.

`obj **is** Class2<T>`

For example

```
 if (obj is Class2<MyT>)
 {
     // Do whatever is it that you want with the object.
     // If you want to use the object as Class2, you can simply cast it
     // to Class2 by using
     ((Class2<MyT>)obj).methodForOnlyClass2();
 }
```

Comment: No, the code provided won't compile, that's the question being asked here.